# Creating database first and code first in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

Please I have a question and I have searched extensively on Google but couldn't get concrete answers.

I have a project. I already used the Identity framework and by this, it generated the database using code first.

I intend to use database-first for subsequent tables.

My questions are below:

1. Can I generate the database first such that it uses same `DbContext` as the code first entities?
2. Will they have separate connection strings?
3. Do I have to continue using code-first, or can the two approaches be combined in a project?

I am actually new to Entity Framework.

Thanks

Comment: If you create your model classes such that they match the database, either by convention or annotation, then it will work. You don't need to use code first Migrations but it's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Can I generate the database first such that it uses same `DbContext` as the code first entities?

No you can't, assuming you're using `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` / `.edmx` to import your database tables you generated into your project.

The reason is, when you use `Code First`, your connection string in the `web.config` will look something like the following:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="YOUR_IDENTITY_CONTEXT_NAME" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=xxx; Initial Catalog=xxx; User Id=xxx; Password=xxx;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But when you use `.edmx` to import tables into models/classes into your project, it won't see your existing connection string you had with `Code First`. Instead, you will have to create a new connection string, which will look like the following:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="YOUR_DATABASE_FIRST_CONTEXT_NAME" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxx|res://*/xxx|res://*/xxx;provider=System...." />
</connectionStrings>
```

> 2. Will they have separate connection strings?

Yes, they will.

> 3. Do I have to continue using code-first, or can the two approaches be combined in a project?

It would be great if you can use `Code First` all the way through, but if you can't, there are other ways you can mix `Code First` and `Database First` approach:

1. Just use 2 separate connection strings

   I typically name the Identity DbContext `AppIdentityDbContext`, while the data context generated by `.edmx` just `AppDbContext`.
2. Use different ORMs other than `Entity Framework`

   You don't have to stick with one ORM in a project. You can use `Entity Framework` for identity stuff, and use something else, such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), for reading.

Comment: David Liang,   Thank you for the insight and thorough answers. However,  I want to ask also,  is there any implications,  maybe security or performance to be having two connection strings?

Comment: @mantics: I don't think so.You need to securely encrypt and store the connection strings after all, regardless there is just 1 or more. The only "drawback" I can think of with having 2 connection strings pointing to the same database is that you might have to keep them in sync, if there is anything changed to the connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I generate the database first such that it uses same DbContext as the code first entities?

Yes, you can. you can generate the database schema by code first, then turn to database first, when you use database first to generate the DbContext, it will follow the rules that you generated by code first.

2. Will they have separate connection strings?

No, I guess that you have to do it manually.

3. Do I have to continue using code-first, or can the two approaches be combined in a project?

It's not a good practice to use both code first and db first in a project, so I would recommend code-first only.

For further information, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680649/is-it-possible-to-mix-database-first-and-code-first-models-with-entity-framework)